# Difference: Meanwhile vs meantime

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

> Meanwhile vs. meantime

Are they really the same? I've been using them interchangeably...

Comment: In the meantime, in between time ... ain't we got fun?

Comment: all of the news reporters now just use "meantime" not "in the meantime"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The dictionary will tell you that they are synonymous; I will tell you that "meanwhile" is more common than "meantime", unless you say "in the meantime".

[image]

I would use "meanwhile", but "in the meantime" is a close second, with "meantime" dead last, in my opinion.  (As you can see, "meantime" used to be as popular as "in the meantime", but now, it occurs more than ten times less.)

Comment: Have you ever seen "meantime" used in such a sentence without the phrase "in the meantime"?

Comment: @edA-qa: Yes, I have, but rarely.

Comment: hm, I don't think your construct 'but [expr]' is fair to the lone 'meantime'; compare this http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=in+the+meantime%2Cmeantime%2Cmeanwhile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 (for my red graph to be meaningful subtract the value of blue one from it) - I think it proves that it does influence the stats very much.

Comment: @unreason.  How's my edit?  It makes sure that "Meantime" is not included in "In the meantime", and instead of adding a word, it makes sure the expression comes at the beginning of a sentence, where it is more fair.

Comment: @drm65, +1that seems more comparable, but I would still note that http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=meanwhile%2Cmeantime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 shows higher frequency of meantime vs meanwhile overall; re usage see http://www.google.com/search?q=%22meantime%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1975,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22meantime%22+-%22in+the+meantime%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbas=0&tbs=lr:lang_1en,bkt:b&tbm=bks&ei=PSUTTqa-Acev8QOu9KCeDg&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7caa2b99db8bf4b5&biw=1404&bih=809 - you might have to dig a bit, but there are nice examples

Comment: @unreason: You didn't include ["Meanwhile" and "Meantime"](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Meanwhile%2CMeantime%2Cmeanwhile%2Cmeantime&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).  As you can see, adding "Meanwhile" to "meanwhile" is higher (in modern times) than adding "Meantime" to "meantime".

Answer (score 5):

Dictionary.com indicates that both words can be used as either a noun or adverb, but I've only heard *meanwhile* used as an adverb and *meantime* used as a noun.

> *Meanwhile*, back at the ranch John was saddling up his horse.
>
> My plane doesn't leave for another two hours, in the *meantime* I'll grab a bite to eat and catch up on some reading.

Answer (score 1):

I've no proof that other people do this, but I certainly use "meanwhile" to mean *during* the occurrence of some other event, but "meantime" to mean *until* the occurrence of some other event.  So "Meanwhile, back at the ranch John was saddling up his horse" -- while you are doing whatever you're doing, John is saddling; but "My plane doesn't leave for another two hours, in the meantime I'll grab a bite to eat and catch up on some reading." -- in the time gap until the plane leaves, I'll have lunch.

Comment: so you basically say that we use *in the meantime* when we have an endpoint, and *meanwhile* when we don't, do you?