# Difference btw "Meanwhile", "in the meanwhile", "meantime", "in the meantime"

Tags: differences

I've gone through the dictionary definitions but I'm honestly still confused. Is there any distinction at all between them?
Can someone please use an example to explain the four words and how they differ, if they do differ?

Comment: 'Meanwhile' and 'in the meantime' seem the most natural to me  (American English). 'in the meanwhile' is slightly more stuffy. 'meantime' I've not heard.

Comment: Or rather 'meantime' I wouldn't use except maybe in informal use, like in a graphic novel. All four expressions mean the same.

Comment: Personally, I would use 'meanwhile' of two actions happening simultaneously. 'Jane unpacked and put away the shopping; meanwhile John was putting the kettle on for tea'. I would use 'in the meantime' of something that happens while waiting for another event. 'Jane should be back from the shops soon; in the meantime, John got the tea cups out and filled the kettle'. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32913/difference-meanwhile-vs-meantime?rq=1 which seems to agree with me.